# Which column datatype to use with MS Access to save a Base64 image?

Tags: ms-access, base64, cac

I know Access 2010 had MEMO column type, however I'm using the 2013 version and I only have `Short Text` and `Long Text`, where only `Short Text` supports `Length` when editing it in `Design View` and up to 256. I need something bigger than that for base64 string.

Comment: [The Memo data type is now called “Long Text”](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-memo-data-type-is-now-called-long-text-dffe5e34-953e-4451-a05e-fba5d9b564b5)

Comment: @HansUp The problem is the Base64 I'm using has a length of 80k characters. The max seems to be 4k.

Comment: From the linked page, *"can store up to about a gigabyte of text, even though controls on forms and reports can only display the first 64,000 characters"* ... far above 4K.  If you're finding an apparent 4K limit, that must be due to your implementation.

Comment: In any case, when you need a field which can store more than 255 characters, make it Memo datatype.  The difference between Access 2010 and 2013 is that Memo is called Long Text.  And if Memo (Long Text) is not satisfactory, you need a different database.

Comment: @HansUp I'm trying to paste the text using the table editor. I'm getting a `The text is too long to be edited` message. Any idea?

Comment: Revise your question to clearly describe the problem you're trying to solve.  If you need to tell us something like *"paste the text using the table editor"*, it would be wise to explain what you're calling the *"table editor"*.

Comment: I don't have the exact code on hand, but I do recall that the only way to overcome  user-interface limits is to use special DAO objects and methods to insert large objects.  You are not going to find a cut-and-paste solution for such large amounts of data.

Comment: See [AppendChunk()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194088(v=office.15).aspx) documentation with an example.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams: As HansUp said: Controls support up to 64k characters. If you say that you are trying to *paste*, that means that you are using a *control*. A "cell" in a datasheet also is a control (textbox).